# Rêver de, rêver à

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Dans le *[Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAver)* on peut lire:

> Malgré la tradition puriste, rêver, au sens propre, se construit le plus souvent avec à dans la langue actuelle: J'ai rêvé à vous cette nuit. On peut admettre que j'ai rêvé de vous est plus élégant, mais il paraît difficile de considérer rêver à comme franchement incorrect (Dupré 1972, p. 2286).

On m'a toujours dit à l'Alliance Française que *rêver à* était incorrect. Maintenant, je les considère comme puristes, mais y a-t-il différence entre *rêver à* et *rêver de* ? Quelle construction est la plus utilisée aujourd'hui ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

« Rêvait de » est nettement plus fréquent que « rêvait à », et la tendance est la même pour d'autres formes conjuguées (*rêvais*, *rêva*, etc.). En fait, *rêver à* sonne vieilli ; la norme aujourd'hui (au moins en France) est *[rêver](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAver) de*.

[image: rêvait de,rêvait à]

Curieusement, il y a une exception à l'infinitif, où les deux propositions sont au coude à coude.

[image: rêver de,rêver à]

*Rêver à* est surtout utiliser dans un sens figuré, où l'on pense sans être endormi mais en laissant sa penser divaguer à quelque chose que l'on désire. *[Daydream](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/daydream)*, donc, avec une connotation positive pour l'objet de la rêverie.

Pour ce qui est de l'article du TLF, note qu'il cite Dupré, sans forcément s'approprier ses propos (ce qui ne me semblerait pas approprié, et même disproportionné, étant donné que je ne dirais pas moi-même « rêver à » au sens propre et rarement dans le sens de *daydream*).

Comment: Merci, Gilles. Très claire, votre réponse.

Answer (score 2):

Rêver, lorsqu'il est utilisé pour signifier une action mentale à l'état de sommeil doit être suivi de "à", sous la même pulsion du génie de la langue française que songer "à" ou penser "à"

- La nuit dernière, Nicole, j'ai rêvé **à** vous...
- La nuit dernière, j'ai rêvé **à** ce moment de mon enfance...

Toutefois, lorsque le verbe "rêver" représente un vœu ou le souhait d'une situation idéale, il doit être suivi de: "de", quand il précède un verbe et librement de "de" ou "à" lorsqu'il précède un nom.

- Je rêve **de** *vivre* à nouveau dans l'abondance.
- Il rêvait tellement **de** *monter* sur le podium.
- Je rêve **d**'un *monde* sans guerre et sans violence.
- Je rêve **à** un *amour* sans fin.

Answer (score 0):

Ces extraits ci-dessous expliquent la nécessité de la préposition *de* après *rêver*. J'omets l'usage de > pour conserver la lisibilité.

<sub>Source: pp 373-374, *The semantics of ‘empty prepositions’ in French* (1996) by Kemmer and Shyldkrot, as part of *Cognitive Linguistics in the Redwoods: The Expansion of a New Paradigm in Linguistics* edited by Eugene H. Casad.</sub>

Assuming that in at least some of these cases the distinction between the å and de expressions is somewhat archaic (insofar as speakers now reject one of the forms), we believe that we are dealing with 
cases in which the earlier mode of expressing the distinction between 
two modes of 'trying' was with a difference in preposition with the 
same lexical root, while the modern language tends to use lexical distinctions, i.e. choice of a verb requiring å vs. one requiring de. Notice 
that in both cases, choice is involved, although in one case it is at the 
level of choice of preposition while in the other it is at the level of 
predicate choice. The difference between these two modes of expression of the semantic distinction in question seems somewhat trivial in 
this light. rather more insignificant than would be suggested by an 
analysis in which the preposition is meaningful where there is a choice 
of prepositions with the same predicate, but meaningless when different verbs are used.
  Let us look at a further example in which the obligatory use of a 
preposition in the infinitive construction is associated with a contrast 
in meaning. The examples in (12), cited in Gougenheim (1959: 12), 
contrast two verbs of similar semantics, *rêver* and *songer*, both of 
which refer to a subject's thought processes.

(12) 
a. Je rêve d'acheter une automobile.      'I dream of buying a car.'
b. Je songe à acheter une automobile.      'I'm thinking of buying a car.'

Here again we find a difference in lexical semantics between the two 
verbs, although in this case we are dealing with formally distinct verb 
roots (unlike the cases of *décider de/se décider à*, etc. considered 
above). Songer indicates that the speaker is actively considering a future purchase, while river, used here in the sense of wishing for something unattainable, does not. The difference in preposition is coherent 
with the fact that songer has as part of its semantics the property of intentionality or purpose directed at the ground that is lacking in the 
verb réver. Moreover, once again there is a contrast in terms of expectations: the lexical semantics of songer include the default 
on the part of the speaker that he/she will carry out the infinitival process; hence the use of à.
  In keeping with our discussion above, we can say in this case that 
while the individual predicates may require a particular preposition, 
the speaker nevertheless has a choice of using a predicate invoking a 
path-goal construal, or one of somewhat similar meaning but lacking 
in such a construal. The preposition that appears in each case is one 
that is compatible with the semantics of the verb, and redundantly en- 
codes the relation between the main verbal process and the infinitival

<sub>Source:  p 183, *French prepositions à and de
in infinitival complements, 
A pragma-semantic analysis* (2008) by Lidia Fraczak, as part of *Adpositions ; Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*  (2008) edited by D Kurzon, S Adler</sub>

Kemmer and Bat-Zeev Shyldkrot analyze the difference between the expressions
songer à faire (“to think of doing”) and rêver de faire (“to dream of doing”,
“to long to do”), as in the examples below, by ascribing the meaning of “actively
considering a future purchase” to the former, and the meaning of “wishing for
something unattainable” to the latter (1995: 374).

(20) Je rêve d’acheter une automobile.       
‘I dream of buying a car.’

(21) Je songe à acheter une automobile.      
‘I’m considering buying a car.’

In terms of our thesis, with songer à, unlike with rêver de, two possibilities are
considered: in this case, “to buy” and “not to buy”, which constitutes “ambivalent
vision” of the fact in question.